# Creating a Salesforce report on Master Detail relationship

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, master-detail

I am trying to create a report on one to many Master-Detail relationships. I need to  get results on Opportunity(Master) related to the many financiers(Detail). The financiers have a picklist field that can approve or deny or approve conditionally. Some opportunities can have one financier approved and others denied. some have denied by all the financiers. I need to get results for the opportunities that were denied by all the financiers they have applied for. When I tried to use the filter to show denied financiers I am getting results for opportunities that were denied but some of the results were approved by another financer. How do I run a logic to discard the opportunities that were approved by at least one financier and denied by all the financiers? I know that this can be achieved by creating a new field on opportunity or by creating a custom report using a visualforce page. Which is the more subtle and feasible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SF admin question rather than coding. You might have better luck at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com.

As a rule of thumb - si this report going to be the only place you need this kind of data. For "clean" solution I'd be tempted to make up to 3 rollup summary fields on Opportunity, something like "count all financiers", "count approved", "count rejected". And then your report gets significantly simpler.

But if it's one-off requirement or other reason you can't do rollups (for example reaching limit of rollup fields / not wanting to waste them on something considered trivial) you might still be able to pull it off with report.

> I need to get results for the opportunities that were denied by all
>   the financiers they have applied for

I'd try with something called "cross filter". Try help articles or this might be a good start: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23697/799

Maybe "Opportunities with Financiers" report, filtered on Financiers.Status = Declined. Plus cross filter saying "Opportunities without Financiers where status != Declined".

Or maybe 2 cross filters. You'll have to experiment a bit.