# Salesforce Report Formula

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a report to show employees without something.  I have a report type "with/without" that is connecting 2 objects.  1. contact 2. observations
The observation.date__c is the date of the observation.  If a contact has not had an observation, the observation.date__ displays "-"
I am trying to either group by this field or replace the "-" with other text.
I have tried to bucket this field, isnull, isblank, if greater than, etc but nothing seems to be working.  I get an error saying that I can not use observation.date__c because it is an object.

Comment: Observations is related list to Contact? or lookup from Contact? If 1st - you should be able to do it with cross filter. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_cross_filters.htm&type=5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Salesforce report on Master Detail relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615626/creating-a-salesforce-report-on-master-detail-relationship)